# Display different images on the same web page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have each div display a different uploaded image but when I try uploading a picture with the second div it instead changes the first div's picture and nothing happens to the second div.

```
<div class="user-img">
    <img src="./images/image.jpg" alt="Avatar" id="photo">
    <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*">
    <label for="file" id="uploadbtn"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i></label>
</div>
<div class="user-img">
    <img src="./images/image.jpg" alt="Avatar" id="photo">
    <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*">
    <label for="file" id="uploadbtn"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i></label>
</div>
<script>
    const img = document.querySelector('#photo');
    const file = document.querySelector('#file');

    file.addEventListener('change', function(){
        const chosenFile = this.files[0];
        if(chosenFile){
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.addEventListener('load', function(){
            img.setAttribute('src',reader.result);});
            reader.readAsDataURL(chosenFile);
        }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two elements with the same ID of file and Photo. ID's Should be unique. In this case you should utilize classes instead.

Then use `document.getElementsByClassName()` to receive an array of elements which you can iterate through and add the event listener to the file elements.

Comment: done that but still bringing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<img>` elements to use class names, rather than id's. Ex:

```
<img src="./images/image.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="photo">
```

Next grab your images using a document.getElementsByClassName() call like the following

```
const imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('photo');
```

Then you can loop through the imgs array and set the src attribute, like so

```
imgs.forEach((img) => {
  img.setAttribute('src', reader.result);
});
```

Comment: Tried this and there is nothing being uploaded now for both div elements